# Windows equivalent of Linux vmstat pswpin and pgfault?

Tags: windows, memory, stat

Is there a way to query Windows for the total number of pages swaped in / out and total amount of page faults? (values found in `/proc/vmstat` on Linux)

I could only find `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory`, but the values are instantaneous.

Thanks